# How to fix ' missing google-api-python-client'? Using Python, Jupyter Notebook and SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to perform speech recognition on some audio files I have using python 3.x, jupyter notebook and SpeechRecognition library but I get:

```
'RequestError: missing google-api-python-client module: ensure that google-api-python-client is set up correctly.'
```

when using recognize_google_cloud even though I already installed it and see 'google-api-python-client when running

```
conda list
```

Things run smoothly when using the default google speech API key.

Code being used is as follows:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with open('file_with_keys.json') as f:
GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS = f.read()

test_audio = sr.AudioFile('audio_file.wav')
with test_audio as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, language = 'es-MX', 
credentials_json=GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS)
```

Expected result consists of transcription of my current file.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Answer (score 0):

Can you publicly share the notebook?  Did you try this in a console rather than notebook, and what are the results if you do?

Also, when you say

> "Things run smoothly when using the default google speech API key."

Can you be more specific as to what that means or how it relates to the problem?  Your not getting an API key error.

For me, I could only get my python code working if I was running in a virtual environment.  Is that happening for your notebook?

See: https://cloud.google.com/python/setup
And: https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/